# Kafka in the plantext mode, what fields do the client need to set in the properties to create a producer?(In Java programs)

Tags: java, apache-kafka

At present, it is determined to use the plan mode, not even SSL. Then I can't find the specific fields to set on the Internet... Please take a look. Thank you very much!

There are some SSL related keys in my code. Should I delete them?

```java
        Properties pro = new Properties();

        String sasl = String.format("org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"%s\"  password=\"%s\";", userName, password);
        pro.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", sasl);
        pro.setProperty("ssl.cipher.suites", suites);   
        pro.setProperty("ssl.enabled.protocols", authorizedEncryptionMode);
        pro.setProperty("security.protocol", protocols);    
        pro.setProperty("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        pro.setProperty("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        for (String ipAndPort : ipAndPorts) {
            pro.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", ipAndPort);
            try(Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(pro)) {
                producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        alarmModel.getString("alarmId"), new Record(alarmModel).toString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("pmRuleDeliverBySouthKafka failed....", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I need your help.

Comment: Your quesiton is confusing, what do you mean by "plantext"? Maybe `PLAINTEXT` ? If so, it means that the listener will be without authentication and non-encrypted. If it is `PLAINTEXT`, why you set SASL-related configuration in your Producer's properties then?

Comment: Bootstrap servers and serializers is the only required property for plaintext mode unless you're asking about SASL_PLAIN